# Entity Framework 4 Code Generation Item Ignoring Custom Tool Namespace

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4

I have a project that runs off a model first entity framework edmx file. I've set the custom tool namespace so that the entities end up in the namespace I want them in. This has worked fine for a while.

I now need to customise the generated code, to that end I have added a code generation item, but the code that this generates by default ignores the custom tool namespace.

Apart from the fact I can edit the tt file, what else is different about the code generation items? Also, any thoughts on how to correct the default code generation item so that it respects the custom tool namespace?

Comment: Is there a patch for VS2010 that fixes the issue where the namespace in the custom tool is ignored and the default namespace of the project is used when creating .edmx files?

Comment: This is where I usually look for VS2010 patches: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads

Answer (score 6):

If you inspect the TT template file you will see a property (in the properties window) that specifies custom tool namespace. Set your namespace here and the template should use this in its code generation, note this is on the TT file, you will need to do this for all TT files you use for your EDMX generation. It does not use the one specified in the EDMX file.

The fix may rectify this behaviour, but don't be scared to dive into the TT. I have a post detailing some changes you may want to make.

http://slappyza.wordpress.com/2010/08/08/getting-the-entity-framework-to-generate-an-interface-for-mocking/

I also spotted a couple of other issues with the VB version. Not sure if they have been fixed.

http://slappyza.wordpress.com/2010/08/03/bug-in-the-ado-net-entity-framework-poco-generator/

Comment: Thank you! If you are going to duplicate entity names, remember to create each .edmx in separate folders to avoid file collisions (Customer.vb, etc).

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution would be to edit the `.tt` file.

You need to find

```
string namespaceName = code.VsNamespaceSuggestion();
```

Then you can replace it with your custom namespace:

```
string namespaceName = "YourCustomNamespace";
```

Answer (score -1):

Change the project's default namespace and rebuild your project.

Comment: Why the downvote? When I had this problem this was the only solution that worked for me...